# AS 9.4: Proc Transpose for Height variable, dont know how to include another column

Tags: sas, transpose, proc

I am using SAS 9.4 and trying to transpose an Excel table with 13 observations and 5 variables.
Specifically, I have something that looks like this:

```
Tree ID    Latin Name           Height  
Pt1       Pinus Taeda           169
Pt1       Pinus Taeda            52
Pt1       Pinus Taeda            34
Pt2       Pinus Taeda            148.7       
Id1       Ilex Decidua            25
Id1       Ilex Decidua            198
Id2       Ilex Decidua             141
```

I am trying to transpose it so that individual trees have a single record recording their multiple height measurements.
Specifically, I’m looking to have something like this:

```
Tree ID   Latin Name   Height 1  Height 2  Height 3 
Pt1      Pinus taeda    169     52       34 
Pt2      Pinus taeda    148.7     .         . 
... ... ... ... ... 
Id1      Ilex Decidua     25     198        .
```

My code so far only gives me the Tree ID column and the Height 1 Height2 Height3 columns with the correct values but I cannot figure out how to get it to also show the Latin Name column?

Comment: Show what code you tried.  Sounds like you just need to add the name variable to your BY statement.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply! I actually got it to work, just needed to include the latin_name variable, as well in the By statement, like you correctly pointed out!

Comment: PROC TRANSPOSE DATA=Tree2 OUT=Tree3(drop=_NAME_ _LABEL_) prefix=Height;
    BY Tree_ID Latin_Name;
    VAR Height;
RUN;

Comment: Your answer is correct. You can add solution to you own question. Next person coming along will surely appreciate when answer is readily available.